# MPLAB X stops at random places in the code when debugging

Tags: debugging, pic, mplab

```
Platform MPLAB X
CPU PIC18F2520
Compiler XC8 v1.38
```

I have an odd problem with the MPLAB X when running in "debug" mode, 
very often when I run in debug mode and starts execution (pressing play button)

The debugger stops at random places in the code (it is fairly random, one or two spots in the code "comes up" more frequently than others).
I do not have any breakpoints or touching the debugger.

There is another problem that might be related.
If I run the debugger the CPU execute all the time 
(except when it randomly stops) if i have the debugger attached, 
but when I disconnect the debugger the CPU execute for some second or so 
and then stops.

Anyone else have experienced the same behaviour ?

Regards Stefan

Answer (score 0):

After further investigations it seems that the ground plane is affected by how the test setup was done After adding opto coupled USB connections for the ICD3 and a Isolation transformer for the target hardware it seems that the problems have disappeared.